# Rails action caching and MimeType

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to use action caching with requests setting the Mime Type header ?

Currently rails seems to store the cache as a key which is the url path but doesn't take care of the Mime Type Header.

Comment: Are you talking about `Accept`? `Content-Type`? Something else?

Comment: I'm talking about Accept